# How to make ongoing wearable notification without "Mute App" action

Tags: android, notifications, watch, wear-os

I am trying to make player notification with play/stop actions that is ongoing. I manage to make ongoing notification on wearable but i can't figure out how to make it without **Mute app action** that added automatically for ongoing notifications. **TuneIn, Google Play Music and PlayerFm** somehow manage to do this so there is way i just can't find it. May be anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. Apparently there is no way to do this trough Notification. What all those apps do - they use [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) to achieve this.